# updateAutonumericInput not changing input values in Shiny application

Tags: r, shiny

I had to use `autoNumericInput` from the `shinyWidgets` library to properly format my input fields. I noticed that the `updateAutoNumericInput` functions in my `observe({...})` reactive is not behaving the same way as `updateNumericInput` from the base `shiny` library. The user input fails to change into my desired output. Check inputs with IDs `gf` and `ba` in the code below.

A somewhat working version of my application: https://zakinzahid.shinyapps.io/loan-repayment-schedule-generator-v2/

Try doing the following:

- Set "Do you want to arrange for a variable payment scheme?" to "Yes"
- Set "Annual Growth Rate" to 5%
- Set "Do you want to arrange for a variable payment scheme?" to "No"
- Set "Do you want to arrange for a variable payment scheme?" to "Yes" again

The "Annual Growth Rate" should still have the value 5%. I need it to be 0%. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Inputs are in the side panel as below:

```
            airDatepickerInput(inputId = "d",
                               label = "When are you planning on taking out the loan?",
                               value = ceiling_date(x = Sys.Date(), unit = "month"),
                               minDate = ceiling_date(x = Sys.Date(), unit = "month"),
                               view = "months", 
                               minView = "months",
                               monthsField = "months",
                               dateFormat = "MM, yyyy"),
            autonumericInput(inputId = "l",
                             label = "Loan Amount:",
                             minimumValue = 1,
                             value = 2000000,
                             align = "left",
                             decimalPlaces = 2,
                             digitGroupSeparator = ",",
                             decimalCharacter = "."),
            autonumericInput(inputId = "i",
                             label = "Annual Interest Rate:",
                             minimumValue = -100,
                             maximumValue = 100,
                             value = 10,
                             align = "left",
                             decimalPlaces = 2,
                             currencySymbol = " %",
                             currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
                             decimalCharacter = "."),
            sliderInput(inputId = "rp",
                        label = "Repayment Period (in years):",
                        min = 1,
                        max = 40,
                        value = 20,
                        step = 1,
                        ticks = F),
            sliderInput(inputId = "gp",
                        label = "Grace Period (in years):",
                        min = 0,
                        max = 39,
                        value = 2,
                        step = 1,
                        ticks = F),
            selectInput(inputId = "f",
                        label = "Frequency of Installments:",
                        choices = list("Annual",
                                       "Biannual",
                                       "Quarterly",
                                       "Monthly"),
                        selected = list("Monthly")),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.gp != 0",
                             radioButtons(inputId = "gpi",
                                          label = "Will you be paying interest accrued during the grace period?",
                                          choices = list("Yes",
                                                         "No"),
                                          selected = list("Yes"),
                                          inline = T)),
            radioButtons(inputId = "g",
                         label = "Do you want to arrange for a variable payment scheme?",
                         choices = list("Yes",
                                        "No"),
                         selected = list("No"),
                         inline = T),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.g == 'Yes' && input.f != 'Annual'",
                             radioButtons(inputId = "gt",
                                          label = "Do you want to maintain level payments within each individual year?",
                                          choices = list("Yes" = "step",
                                                         "No" = "continuous"),
                                          selected = list("Yes" = "step"),
                                          inline = T)),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.g == 'Yes'",
                             autonumericInput(inputId = "gf",
                                              label = "Annual Growth Rate:",
                                              minimumValue = -100,
                                              maximumValue = 100,
                                              value = 0,
                                              align = "left",
                                              decimalPlaces = 2,
                                              currencySymbol = " %",
                                              currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
                                              decimalCharacter = ".")),
            radioButtons(inputId = "b",
                         label = "Are you expecting to make a fixed balloon/drop payment?",
                         choices = list("Yes",
                                        "No"),
                         selected = list("No"),
                         inline = T),
            conditionalPanel(condition = "input.b == 'Yes'",
                             autonumericInput(inputId = "ba",
                                              label = "Balloon/Drop Payment Amount:",
                                              minimumValue = 0,
                                              maximumValue = 2000000*(1.1)^20,
                                              value = 0,
                                              align = "left",
                                              decimalPlaces = 2,
                                              digitGroupSeparator = ",",
                                              decimalCharacter = ".")),
            actionButton(inputId = "calc",
                         label = "Generate Schedule", width = "100%")
```

I tried to update the values inside of the server variable as below:

```
    observe({
        
        # Update grace period input parameters
        updateSliderInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "gp",
                          max = min(input$rp - 1, 5))
        
        # Update balloon payment amount input parameters
        updateAutonumericInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "ba",
                          options = list(maximumValue = input$l*(1+input$i)^input$rp))
        
        # Update year input parameters
        updateSliderInput(session = session,
                          inputId = "y",
                          min = ifelse(booleanConvert(input$gpi),
                                       1,
                                       input$gp + 1),
                          max = input$rp)
        
        # Update growth factor
        if (input$g == "No") updateAutonumericInput(session = session, inputId = "gf", value = 0)
        
        # Update amount of balloon payment
        if (input$b == "No") updateAutonumericInput(session = session, inputId = "ba", value = 0)
        
        # Update grace period interest payment boolean
        if (input$gp == 0) updateRadioButtons(session = session, inputId = "gpi", selected = list("No"))
        
        # Hide all tabs in the beginning
        if (input$calc == 0) {
            
            hideTab(inputId = "Main", 
                    target = "Annual Overview")
            hideTab(inputId = "Main", 
                    target = "Monthly Breakdown")
            
        } else {
            
            showTab(inputId = "Main", 
                    target = "Annual Overview")
            showTab(inputId = "Main", 
                    target = "Monthly Breakdown")
            
            # Hide annual breakdown tab
            if (input$f == "Annual") {
                
                hideTab(inputId = "Main", 
                        target = "Monthly Breakdown")
                
            } else {
                
                showTab(inputId = "Main", 
                        target = "Monthly Breakdown")
                
            }
            
        }
        
    })
```

PS: First time writing code for a Shiny application. Really sorry if the code is messy and not exactly in line with common practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `observeEvent` is better in this situation instead of `observe`.  Try this

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons(inputId = "g",
               label = "Do you want to arrange for a variable payment scheme?",
               choices = list("Yes",
                              "No"),
               selected = list("No"),
               inline = T),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.g == 'Yes' && input.f != 'Annual'",
                   radioButtons(inputId = "gt",
                                label = "Do you want to maintain level payments within each individual year?",
                                choices = list("Yes" = "step",
                                               "No" = "continuous"),
                                selected = list("Yes" = "step"),
                                inline = T)),
  conditionalPanel(condition = "input.g == 'Yes'",
                   autonumericInput(inputId = "gf",
                                    label = "Annual Growth Rate:",
                                    minimumValue = -100,
                                    maximumValue = 100,
                                    value = 0,
                                    align = "left",
                                    decimalPlaces = 2,
                                    currencySymbol = " %",
                                    currencySymbolPlacement = "s",
                                    decimalCharacter = "."))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$g, {
    # Update growth factor
    if (input$g == "No") updateAutonumericInput(session = session, inputId = "gf", value = 0)
    
    print(input$gf)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint @YBS. Putting each of the input update functions into thier own `observe` or `observeEvent` worked. I think I'll just stick to doing things this way going forward. Have a good day!